# threejs traverse an object onClick

Tags: javascript, three.js

i want to add wireframe for an object onClick the button, so am using `traverse` to do it, it is working fine in the OBJMTLLoder, if a try it with the separate function like below onclick the button it cause

> object is undefined

```
 function wireframe(object){
                 //alert('hhhhhh');

                object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )
                    {
                    //child.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
                    var  geometry = child.geometry;
                    //console.log(geometry);
                    //geometry.dynamic = true;
                    material = child.material;
                     mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                        scene.add(mesh);

                    var useWireFrame = true;
                        if (useWireFrame) {
                            mesh.traverse(function (child) {
                                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) 
                                {
                                //child.material.wireframe = true;

                                var wfh = new THREE.WireframeHelper( mesh, 0xffffff );
                                wfh.material.wireframe = true;
                                wfh.material.linewidth = 2; // looks much better if your PC will support it
                                scene.add( wfh );                       

                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }
                    });



                }
```

can we traverse on the object onclick, is it possible ?? why am getting the error ??

Comment: can you provide an example of your onClick?

Comment: Hi, here it is onClick="wireframe();"

Comment: oh i don't think onCLick is what i though it was in the normal sense, i was thinking it was a listener, but a couple of things why is wireframe in "" and also you have not passed it an object so it is undefined

Comment: don't need to pass object in the function we can get directly in three.js, so i want to know how to get it, i know we must pass the arguments in the function in basic

Comment: There are two issues with the code. First you do have to pass an object to wireframe. Then the second `traverse()` is not needed. You are traversing on a `mesh` and you are looking for a `mesh`.

Comment: Hi @gaitat if i pass object via function it says same error, i can't understand your comment, can you explain briefly ?

Comment: Just as @Quince said, you need to pass an object to the function, unless it is global. But in this case it is not because you pass it as a variable. What error does it say.

Comment: object is globally declared and am getting `object is undefined` error.

Comment: if a pass object as `onClick="wireframe('object');"` it doesn't show any error but i can't get wireframe

Comment: Hi @gaitat now i can `traverse` with mesh i have no error, but the wireframe apply as a small dot in the object, it is so wired

Comment: hi @gaitat i got it,now the wireframe is working on the click, but it is only working with the object loaded with `OBJLoader` and it dashing a dot on the object instead of wireframe on `OBJMTLLoader`, am doing anything wrongly ?

Comment: sorry but I dont understand what "it dashing a dot on the object" means?

Comment: meaning that it only showing the wireframe on some area of the object, not the full object

Comment: you can check it here, http://3dmodelviewer.osiztechnologies.com/threejs/examples/wireframe.php, while click the Add WF you can see the that it only applying in the left hand of the object with the red color as a dot, but here it is working well http://3dmodelviewer.osiztechnologies.com/threejs/examples/wireframe_obj.php

Comment: Hi @gaitat, do you have answer for this issue ?? on load `OBJMTLLoader` the wireframe is working well, but if we call `WireframeHelper` on other custom function it doesn't, i used mesh `traverse` that also doesn't work, really struggling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to add wireframe appearance to your object. One is to add a `THREE.WireframeHelper` to the scene. That is what you have done with the ladybug model and when the user presses the On button you `add()` the wireframe to the scene and when the user presses the Off button you `remove()` the wireframe object from the scene.

With the male model (the one that does not work) you wanted to look for the object material and go and change that.

You should load your model normally:

```
// this is asynchronous loading
// add a name to the object so you can search for it later.
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.load( 'obj/male02/male02.obj', 'obj/male02/male02_dds.mtl',
    function ( object ) { object.name = 'name you want'; scene.add ( object ) } );

function wireframe() {
    var object = scene.getObjectByName ("name you want", true); // recursive search

    object.traverse ( function (child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
            child.material.wireframe = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @gaitat, thanks again for the awesome answer, and the wireframe is applying here, and however i want the wireframe as like in the `THREE.WireframeHelper` meaning that the wireframe is looks like outer material of the object, not the wireframe is combined with object material

Comment: That is why I said there are a couple of ways to this thing. You cannot achieve the same effect so you have to pick which to use in each case.

Comment: Hi @gaitat, thanks for the answer, is it possible to set the wireframe color, if i set `child.material.color.setHex(0xff0000);` it looks only aplly on the material not on the wireframe

Comment: and if i off the wireframe still the color is set into object, so i can't get back to the object material color

Comment: You can change the wireframe color when you use the WireframeHelper().  For your second question, I think I mentioned, you need to save off the original material. It will be tricky if the object has multiple materials.

Comment: thank you @gaitat i will try it myself and let you know, make me sure that we can use wireframe helper for any kind of object loader ?

Comment: Yes, it has nothing to do with the loader. Just have in mind that you add extra geometry to your scene when you use the `WireframeHelper()`

Comment: oh ok, but in the given example of me, `WireframeHelper()` is only working for the .obj model only, if we use it with .obj and .mtl it is wired, that the wireframe only apply only on some portion of the object, not on the entire object, to apply on the entire object we are using object `traverse()` am i right?

Comment: Yes you should use `traverse()` to apply wireframe to the entire object.

Comment: `traverse()` also not working to apply the` WireframeHelper()` to the entire object

Comment: There are a couple of ways to add wireframe appearance to your object. One is to add a THREE.WireframeHelper to the scene. This allows you to also change the color of the wireframe. The other is to use the `traverse()` function to change the material to add `material.wireframe = true`. You should not confuse the two.