# threejs wireframe helper with object traverse

Tags: three.js

i want to apply the WireframeHelper to the object that is loaded using OBJMTLLoder objects, i know that i must do the traverse the mesh to apply it on the entire object, so here i tried like below

```
mesh.traverse ( function (child) {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
        {

        wfh = new THREE.WireframeHelper( mesh,whfcolor );
        wfh.material.depthTest = false;
        wfh.material.opacity = 0.25;
        wfh.material.transparent = true;
        scene.add( wfh );    
        }

     });
```

but it is not working the wireframe is only apply on the some part of the object only, not the entire object, it is working fine with the `OBJLoader` alone

Comment: I believe question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385550/ sums it up.